# ResultSet containing EnumSet produces Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, kotlin, jdbc

I have an Enum like

```
enum class AmenitiesEnum {
POOL,
PETS_ALLOWED
// shortened list, for demo purpose only
}
```

This Enum gets included in a class that then gets persistent in a MySQL database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotels")
class Hotel (

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
override val id: Int? = null,

override val name: String,

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
val rating: RatingsEnum?,

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
val rooms : List<Room> = ArrayList<Room>(),

// below code seems to be the issue

@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
val amenities: Set<AmenitiesEnum> = EnumSet.noneOf(AmenitiesEnum::class.java)
) : Accommodation, Serializable
```

I initialize the database with demo values

```
CREATE TABLE hotels (
id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(125) NOT NULL,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
type ENUM('BED_AND_BREAKFAST', 'SPA') DEFAULT NULL,
rating ENUM('HALF_STAR', 'ONE_STAR', 'TWO_STARS', 'THREE_STARS', 'FOUR_STARS', 'FIVE_STARS') DEFAULT NULL,
amenities SET('POOL','PETS_ALLOWED','PARKING_INCLUDED', 'BAR', 'DISABLED_FRIENDLY', 'FREE_DRINKS', 'WIFI') DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO hotels VALUES (NULL, 'First ever Hotel', 'First hotel ever build. Amazing.', null, 'one_star', 'bar');
SELECT @last := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO rooms VALUES
(NULL, @last, 2, 'QUEEN', 'PETS_ALLOWED'),
(NULL, @last, 1, 'SINGLE', 'PETS_ALLOWED'),
(NULL, @last, 3, 'KING', 'PETS_ALLOWED');
```

When I start the app and fire a query against the database I get

```
... binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
... SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
... Table '_database_.hotel_amenities' doesn't exist
... Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.katanox.hotelbooking.domain.room.value.Room["hotel"]->com._.hotelbooking.domain.hotel.value.Hotel["amenities"])]
```

Why does MySQL state `Table 'd035b60f.hotel_amenities' doesn't exist` and how can I fix this? Changing the type to List instead of EnumSet results in the same error.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the DEBUG, Hibernate translates this to:

```
select
    amenities0_.hotel_id as hotel_id1_0_0_,
    amenities0_.amenities as amenitie2_0_0_ 
from
    hotel_amenities amenities0_ 
where
    amenities0_.hotel_id=?
```

I'm still looking for a solution to the problem, any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Because it is a collection of values, which cannot be expressed in a single column (at least not from the JPA point of view without additional work). That also applies to `@ElementCollection` it needs to know how to map, by default it maps it to a different table with a foreign-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom JPA attribute converter for this purpose that maps this to a string. On the JDBC level, as far as I understood, this has to be represented as comma separated string. See the documentation for an example on how to use it: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html